# Android dialog animation effect

Tags: android, animation, dialog

I am new to android development.

I want to display a dialog on activity load.

The animation details:

1. After some times lets say 2secs, the dialog should be fade away and zoom out.
2. Finally become a small square in the center of the screen. (both horizontally and vertically)
3. After that the small square should move to top with effect which forms an icon in the top bar.

Is there anyway to do that?I have gone through several tutorials but cant find an effect like this.
Please help.

Comment: Use Scale Animation for Dialog to make it Bigger and Smaller and Use Translate Animation to move square icon image to move it from bottom to top.

Comment: Use Alpha animation to FadeIn, FadeOut your dialog.